# Format 3589 as 00:35:89 using SQL SELECT Sum

Tags: mysql, sql

```
userName    date        startTime                   endTime                     total 

bobJohn     2014-06-05  2014-06-05 02:19:20.000000  2014-06-05 02:19:22.000000  00:00:02.000000     
bobJohn     2014-06-05  2014-06-05 02:19:25.000000  2014-06-05 02:19:26.000000  00:00:01.000000     
bobJohn     2014-06-05  2014-06-05 02:19:29.000000  2014-06-05 02:19:31.000000  00:00:02.000000     
bobJohn     2014-06-05  2014-06-05 02:24:35.000000  2014-06-05 02:59:21.000000  00:34:46.000000     
bobJohn     2014-06-05  2014-06-05 03:04:41.000000  2014-06-05 03:04:43.000000  00:00:02.000000     
bobJohn     2014-06-05  2014-06-05 03:04:49.000000  2014-06-05 03:06:25.000000  00:01:36.000000
```

---

SQL query --> ***SELECT SUM('total') FROM timeSheet;***

result --> ***3589***

Question --> How do I format the result in 00:00:00 so that the total from the query would instead be ***00:35:89*** and/or ***00:35:89.000000***?

I'm a noob at SQL...Would I need to include a "format as 00:00:00" somewhere in my SQL? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sql server? They are not the same thing.

Comment: Sorry. I am using mysql.

Comment: What is the data type of the `total` column?  Type `desc [tablename]` to see.

Comment: Time is the data type of the total column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sec_to_time` to convert your number to a timestamp. Then use `date_format` to format your timestamp as a date. Would look something like this:

```
select date_format(sec_to_time(sum('total')), '%h:%i:%s') from timeSheet
```